# Handlebars js if condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, handlebars.js

My json part:

```
var context = {
  author: [{
  id: 47,
  name: "Yehuda Katz"
},
{
  id: 48,
  name: "Kate"
},
```

{
      id: 49,
      name: "Jim"
    }

]}

Handlebars

```
{{if author}}
 <li>{{id}}</li>
 <li>{{name}}</li>
{{/if}}
```

I want to display the contents once author key is present. If not,it won't display.

However,my above code doen't displays the author eventhough it is present.

Whats wrong in my code??

Comment: Hash character before the if:  `{{#if author}}`

Comment: i used it also but not works..

Answer (score 1):

Handlebars block helpers (like if) need a hash character before the block statment

so instead of

```
{{if author}}
 <li>{{id}}</li>
 <li>{{name}}</li>
{{/if}}
```

do

```
{{#if author}}
 <li>{{id}}</li>
 <li>{{name}}</li>
{{/if}}
```